# Sum up amount in parquets using Java API

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am new to Spark in java. I have multiple parquets in HDFS whose paths are stored in a `String[] paths` and the parquets are in this format:

```
Amount |  User
10     |  User1
```

Now I want to calculate the sum of amounts in all parquets, how should I do this?

Is it enough to do:

```
sparkSession.read().parquet(paths)
```

or do I need to first do a `union` or `join`?

Comment: `sparkSession.read().parquet(paths)` is enough

Comment: @QuickSilver Hi thank you for your answer ! How can I sum up this list of amount : sparkSession.read().parquet(paths).select(col(Constant.Amount)) ? I need one double number at the end

Answer (score 0):

`sparkSession.read().parquet(paths)` should load all your parquet data in a single go

You can use below code to get the **sum of Amount** column

```
val sumDf = df.agg(functions.sum("Amount"))
    val sum = sumDf.collectAsList().get(0).getDouble(0)
    println(sum)
```

Note: `Amount` should be of type Double for above code to work

Answer (score 0):

sparkSession.read().parquet(paths) is good enough to read all parquet